# How to join only one column?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

I need to join only one column from table 2, say first_name.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "select one column from table 2":

```
   SELECT table1.*, table2.first_name
     FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
...
```

Comment: Exactly. And, what till now no one mentionned, explicit is better han implicit; it is better to list the wanted columns instead of just saying "all"

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted, thanks a lot NullUserException :)

Comment: This answer produces the desired functional results but it doesn't address the underlying question of efficiency/performance: conceptually, the Join is performed first (including all fields from both tables) and then only the specified Select statement columns are filtered-in to the final result.  But is there a way, for efficiency reasons, to explicitly specify a *join* of only column 'first_name' from table2? Or do all modern optimizers automatically do that?

Comment: @pstraton The original question doesn't mention performance, but it's a good question. Maybe you could post it yourself if it's not covered elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

**The accepted answer is the correct answer but I have encountered a strange error when the tables are in two different databases:**

Assuming that table1 is in database1 and table2 is in database2.
Initially I have tried this:

```
SELECT *, database2.table2.first_name 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN database2.table2
ON database1.table1.id = database2.table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

The strange thing is that if I try this query from PHP PDO there were no errors but the result contained all columns from database2.table2 (expected only first_name column).

But if I have tried the same query from phpmyadmin got a sintax error:

*Table 'database2.table1' doesn't exist*

**So, for solve that, then all databases need to be specified implicitly like this**:

```
SELECT database1.table1.*, database2.table2.first_name 
FROM database1.table1
LEFT JOIN database2.table2
ON database1.table1.id = database2.table2.table1_id
WHERE database1.table1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Take your original code and substitute * with table1.*, table2.YourChosenColumn

```
 SELECT table1.*, table2.YourChosenColumn
 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
 WHERE table1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in addition to your already stated query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.id = 1 and table1.first_name = table2.first_name
```

Comment: No, this is not what I meant, there is no first_name in table1, I just need first_name from table2. thank you for your answer :)